# Location "/" did not match any routes

Tags: react-router

Really I do not see what is going on, spent all day trying to figure out what is wrong.

Upgraded version react-router: "^1.0.3" and "history": "^1.17.0"

And always got this nice warning message:

> Warning: Location "/" did not match any routes

Router is here
https://github.com/darul75/web-react/blob/master/app/app-dev.js#L7

My routes
https://github.com/darul75/web-react/blob/master/app/routes.js

Was looking to debug with stack but tricky there

```
function matchRoutes(routes, location, callback) {}
```

no success, any one to help me would be so nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `app-dev.js`, change

`import Router from 'react-router';` to `import {Router} from 'react-router';`

and

`const routes = require('./routes');` to `import routes from './routes';`

Comment: nice catch @Thomas, done but no change about previous result

Comment: I caught another one ! It "fixes" your warning.